# Addition over zoo/xts objects in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I have two `xts` objects of different lengths in `R`, defined as:

```
library(xts)
seq <- seq(as.POSIXct("2015-09-01"),as.POSIXct("2015-09-02"), by = "1 hour")
ob1 <- xts(data.frame(val=1:(length(seq))),seq)
seq2 <- seq(as.POSIXct("2015-09-01"),as.POSIXct("2015-09-03"), by = "1 hour")
ob2 <- xts(data.frame(val=1:(length(seq2))),seq2)
```

Now when I perform addition over `ob1` and `ob2` as

```
ob1 + ob2
```

I get the result, but the addition is done over the timestamps which are common in both. Is there a way where I can retain all the distinct timestamps of both the objects and still get the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the prettiest solution, but from the top of my head...

```
test<-merge(ob1,ob2)
test<-xts(rowSums(test, na.rm=T), order.by = time(test))
```